# Slow mysql subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to optimise a slow query, it takes about 5 minutes to run on my computer, approximately the same time on my server(that has 8gb of ram)

```
SELECT
    buyer_id as bid,
    date_sold as dsold,
    (
        SELECT seller_id
        FROM sale
        WHERE buyer_id = bid
        ORDER BY date_acquired
        LIMIT 1
     ) as sid
from sale
WHERE seller_id = 3585328;
```

I've created a test-index for this query.

```
| sale  |          1 | test                |            1 | buyer_id         | A         |     4900222 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sale  |          1 | test                |            2 | date_acquired    | A         |    14700667 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
```

When I run an explain, i get

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT buyer_id as bid,date_sold as dsold, (SELECT seller_id FROM sale WHERE buyer_id = bid ORDER BY date_acquired LIMIT 1) as sid from sale WHERE seller_id = 3585328;
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | sale  | ref  | test          | test | 8       | const | 12466 | Using index                              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sale  | ref  | test          | test | 8       | func  |     3 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
```

I understand that a subquery might be slow, But I'm running out of ideas on how to optimise. 
I'm not sure if it is significant but if i group by buyer_id, the query runs significantly faster. 
Replacing with a join feels tricky since I'm relying on "Limit 1" in my subquery.

Comment: Is that date_acquired index descending or ascending ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something here but won't your subquery just return the buyer ID specified in your `WHERE` clause every time? In which case, what is the point of it?

Comment: `slow mysql`, isn't one of those words redundant?

Comment: cmq_mgr, sorry, I added the wrong select statement in the subquery when I wrote the question.

Comment: You show `EXPLAIN` from wrong query. Provide plan from correct query.

Comment: @iiro, all indexes are created ascending. The ASC,DESC tag on create index is only for future references, it is not implemented(According to the mysql documentation).

Comment: You had better provide a SQLfiddle or at least some sample data together with expected results; it isn't at all clear what you're trying to obtain. Here if seller 3585328 sold two items to the same buyer, it looks like you'd get two rows with a duplicate `sid`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your query seems strange to me. Unless I don't get what you want to do, I don't event understand why you do this subquery, as you want to get "buyer_id" but where buyer_id = 3585328;

Second, event if this is a typo, and you want to do something else, if you ORDER BY date_acquired, you should have an index on date_acquired;

Comment: Sorry it was my misstake. I changed the subquery to reflect its proper use. It is supposed to return seller_id. 
About the indexes, since mysql can't use two indexes for the same query, aren't I supposed to have an index on (buyer_id, date_acquired)?

Comment: What do you want to get ? The most recent buyer for a given seller ? The most recent seller for a given buyer ?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose here is to get the most recent `sid` only; try something like:

```
SELECT
    t1.buyer_id AS bid,
    t1.date_sold AS dsold,
    t1.id AS sid
FROM
    sale AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sale AS t2
    ON (t1.buyer_id = t2.buyer_id AND t1.date_acquired < t2.date_acquired)
WHERE t2.date_acquired IS NULL;
```